# Can I buy cocoa butter squares for cooking?

Tags: cocoa

In the 70's, I used to be able to buy cocoa butter squares - like unsweetened chocolate - made by Hershey's.  They no longer make it.  I made white chocolate fudge with it.  Is there anything out there like that now?  I'd really like to make some of this fudge again for my daughter and grandchildren.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can certainly buy cocoa butter, from many different brands. I have seen more chips than squares, but the shape doesn't matter.

We don't do shopping recommendation for brands here, and suggesting single stores is also not looked upon well, especially since most people reading this won't live in the same place as you. So I won't send you somewhere special, I'll just say, if you can't find it in a well sorted supermarket, try in a specialty store for confiserie, and if you can't find that one, try online.

Comment: Just be sure it's food grade - it's apparently also sold for topical use, so when you're shopping on the web, make sure it's for eating, not makeup. :D

Comment: I'd have to buy it online as I live in the boondocks.  I saw the chips online, but how much would equal one of those little squares?